# map has list as value check if null

Tags: java-8

I have a Map in Java 8.

I need to check if the list that comprises the map value is empty or null and return the result .

I have tried likewise with no luck

```
public boolean mapValuesEmpty() {
boolean result = true;
    for (Entry<Integer, List<SomeObjectName>> entry : eventLogsMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() != null) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: what do you mean *with no luck*? Exception/invalid result/what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 boolean result = eventLogsMap
                     .values()
                     .stream()
                     .anyMatch(list -> list != null && !list.isEmpty())
```